# Froala PHP SDK error: Fieldname is not correct. It must be: file

Tags: php, editor, wysiwyg, froala

I'm developing an article-publishing utility and I'm using Froala's WYSIWYG textarea text editor that I included in a form, after storing the article's basic infos in the database, I want to store the uploaded images in the text editor on the server , the problem is when I use their php SDK to store images like mentioned in the documentation, I get this error: **Fieldname is not correct. It must be: file**

this is the html for the form:

```
<form method="post" class="mt-5" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <label for="uname" style="color:#B1DDF1;"><b>Your Article's title</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="focusedInput" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Make it creative!...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-2">
                <label for="comment" style="color:#B1DDF1;"><b>Content goes here...</b></label>
                <div id="editor"><textarea  class="form-control" cols="200" rows="200"id='edit' name="file" placeholder="Type some text"><h1>This is a heading</h1>
                    <p>start writing your article here!</p></textarea></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" row mt-2 justify-content-center">
                <input type="submit" class=" col-xs-6" value="Publish me!">
            </div>
        </form>
```

and here is a part of the PHP code:

```
 $lastid=$conn->lastInsertId(); // get the new article's id for ressources management 
      $newarticfold="../LIGHT/articles_ressources/".$lastid; 
      try{
        if(mkdir($newarticfold)){
          require("wysiwygphp/lib/FroalaEditor.php");
          $path="/Freelancing/CarthageP/test/LIGHT/articles_ressources/".$lastid."/"; //specifying the path from $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
          $resp=FroalaEditor_Image::upload($path);
          echo("<div class='alert alert-success'>yaaay images got uploaded yaaaaay</div>");
        }
        
      }
```

I tried changing the name of the textarea to file, read the documentation many times and I tried to google the error message but I didn't find anything regarding it, what can be a possible cause for such a problem and how could it be fixed? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As this is a rather expensive commercial paid plugin did you contact the support of froala?

Comment: Please check phpinfo() if you already have the FileInfo extension activated  __FROM THE MANUAL__  -  Note: For image upload, please make sure your server has the FileInFo extension enabled.   https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Thank you for commenting, I checked and I have fileinfo extension enabled, ill double check or perhaps re-enable it, I also contacted the support and waiting for their response now